# My (other) Moto G3 won't update to the latest Android version

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola

I have two Moto G3 phones (XT1541), the older one is on Android 6.0.1 and the newer(!) one is still on Android 6.0. Why is it not updating to 6.0.1 ?

The phones are international versions and the only difference I can think of is that the older phone is a 8 GB variant and the newer is a 16 GB variant...but the size of internal memory shouldn't matter, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the updates to some units are just VERY late:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-3rd-Gen/Moto-G3-not-updating-from-Android-6-0-to-Android-6-0-1/td-p/3386562

I think that these were my last Motorolas now that even Samsung is better with updates.